# Get URL Param to Auth Login Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, get-request, getmethod

I've trying to get the `url param` of this

`http://localhost:8000/login?merchId=ABC&param1=abc123&param2=abc123`

These params are sent from another site whenever they are redirecting to my login page and the login page of my project should get all these params and perform some logical task in my controller.

As stated above, I need to get the value of ff:

`merchId, param1 and param2`

In `php native`, I can simply use this code just to get these params

using this:

```
$merchId = $_GET['merchId'];
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$param2 = $_GET['param2'];
```

But there's another way to do this.

Currently my login for my project that I'm using is `Auth`

Here's my **LoginController.php** where I want to use and get the url params and perform some stuffs.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user){
        if($user->is_admin == 1){
            return  redirect('/admin/view/all');
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/reseller/reservation/view');
        }
    }


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Here's my **Route**

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Route::group(['middleware'=> ['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/reseller/reservation/view','ResellerController@reservation');
    Other routes included here no need to show......
});
```

Here's my **HomeController**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{   

    $searched = 0;
    $reseller = User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where('is_blocked', '0')  
    ->where('is_admin', '0')          
    ->paginate(20);
    return view('pages.admin.view', compact('reseller', 'searched'));    
}

public function admin(Request $req){
    return view('middleware')->withMessage("Admin");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Retrieving Input From The Query String

While the input method retrieves values from entire request payload (including the query string), the query method will only retrieve values from the query string:

```
$name = $request->query('name');
```

If the requested query string value data is not present, the second argument to this method will be returned:

```
$name = $request->query('name', 'Helen');
```

You may call the query method without any arguments in order to retrieve all of the query string values as an associative array:

```
$query = $request->query();
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input)

Comment: Hello, tried that too to my LoginController and put if the get is working properly but nothing happens `$name = $request->query('name'); return redirect('/reseller/reservation/view?cust='.$name);` The redirect works fine but the `cust` parameter doesn't have value since I tried to put `$name on it. is there any problem with this code?

Comment: @KingRG No, that code should work, unless the query is empty. These examples are straight from the documentation and will work. When it doesn't, it shouldn't be in this part.

Comment: Hmm I think the LoginController didn't get the value of url params.

Comment: Dump the `$request` to see what it did get, that's where I would start debugging.

Comment: As I tried the second argument on your answer where if the requested query string value is not present `helen` will replace as new value. and when I tried on mine helen comes up. The controller doesn't recognize or get the `name` and its value

Comment: @KingRG if this `http://localhost:8000/login?merchId=ABC&param1=abc123&param2=abc123` is your URL, you should work with `$request->query('merchId)'`, because it sounds like your URL doesn't have a param called `name`.

Comment: Yes I replaced, name as `param1` still doesnt give me some value. just wrong explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197209/discussion-between-douwe-de-haan-and-king-rg).

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found my solution..

In my **login.blade.php,**

I tried to get the url params using this code

```
 if(isset($_GET['merchId'])){
 $merchId = $_GET['merchId'];
 }else{
 $merchId = "none";
 }
```

and put a hidden textbox contains the value of `merchId` inside of my `Form Action`

something like

```
   <input type="text" name="merchId" value="<?= $merchId ?>" >
```

and In my **LoginController.php** I put this code to show if the controller gets the request from the `login.blade.php`

Inside of `protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)`

```
   return $request->all();
```

and this turns out to like this

```
    {"_token":"2UvDCxls3WY27h8GpEJTJ8oZytfl1LmkseIU0hWY","merchId":"22","email":"keighdee@gmail.com","password":"mycrush"}
```

I know this one ain't a good practice but still feel free to answer or comment on this question if you have a better answer for this problem